# The addition of geom_segment to my ggplot code gives me the error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Depth' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having some difficulty adding a second layer (of a second dataset) onto my plot in ggplot2.

The general structure of my first dataset, data.scores, is imaged below:

```
             NMDS1     NMDS2     Pond     Depth  ...
sample-1     -0.36     -0.07     L        1
sample-2      0.66     -0.23     L        2
sample-3      0.58     -0.22     L        3
...
```

The general structure of my second dataset, env_fit_df, is imaged below:

```
              MDS1     MDS2     biogeochem
GOAlocation  -0.12    -0.08     GOA
```

The following code creates a figure I am happy with:

```
p <- ggplot(data = data.scores, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, color = Pond, shape = Depth)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(fill = Pond)) +
  xlab(paste0("NMDS1")) +
  ylab(paste0("NMDS2")) +
  coord_fixed()
```

However, the issue arises as I try to add `geom_segment` for a vector over my plot:

```
p <- ggplot(data = data.scores, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2, color = Pond, shape = Depth)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, aes(fill = Pond)) +
  xlab(paste0("NMDS1")) +
  ylab(paste0("NMDS2")) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_segment(data=env_fit_df, aes(x=0,xend=env_fit_df$MDS1,y=0,yend=env_fit_df$MDS2),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")), colour = "grey")
```

The error I am receiving:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Depth' not found
```

Could anyone provide some advice?  I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe include `inherit.aes = FALSE` in your `geom_segment()`?

Comment: That worked.  Thank you, Tung!

Comment: No problem. Fee free to answer your own question. That might help future readers